# How does daily reputation limit treat more than 20 upvotes in a single day?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Say a user have a very good answer that recieves more than 20 up votes in a single day.

As every up vote worth +10 rep, this exceed the daily limit.

For the sake of the example, let us say the answer received 30 up votes.

What will be the final rep gain? will it be +200 on the first day then +100 on the second day (30 up votes * 10 rep points), or the user will get only +200.

Answer (score 21):

Reputation that goes over the daily rep cap does not carry over to the next day. Once you earn 200 rep for the day, you will stop earning rep from *most* sources for the rest of the day. The two exceptions to this is reputation that is earned from accepted answers, and reputation that is earned from bounties.

So in your example, if you earned 30 upvotes in a single day, then you'll only gain 200 rep from the first 20 upvotes. The next 10 upvotes won't give you any rep, not on the day that you hit the rep cap, and not on any of the subsequent days afterwards either.

For more details, see [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) on Meta Stack Exchange.