# How come I keep gaining reputation whereas I've reached the daily limit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I noticed something weird (or at least, something that I *find* weird because I haven't the answer yet). I have reached the daily-reputation limit on SO that is `200` and yet, I still gain reputation from upvotes.

How come?

[I get that there are two exceptions to it which are accepted answers and bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267285/how-does-daily-reputation-limit-treat-more-than-20-upvotes-in-a-single-day). I don't have any bounties and the extra reputation gained today came from an upvote to an answer I made as per the screenshot.

[image]

I am pretty sure my reputation went from 1,425 to 1,435.

Is that a bug? Is there something I'm not yet aware of? Or am I mistaking and I've been stuck at 1,435 where it should have raised to 1,445 (but still, I'm 100% sure I have gained some reputation from those +52 extra points)?

Thanks for lightening me out!

Comment: Accepts and bounties are not affected by the cap. I see what could be at least two accepts in that list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 6 accepted answers today, making your limit for the day:

```
 200 + ( 15 * 6 ) = **290**
```

reputation points.

Comment: Oh right. So I must understand that accepts and bounties are not **even counted** when the daily limit is **calculated**? That means I am able to gain like 400 reputation points if I write enough accepted answers for it to happen?

Comment: Exactly. [15ch]

Comment: Thanks! One last thing: does the counter stop when the limit is reached or does it keep increasing? If so, how are we told the limit has been reached? If not, I do I know the extra reputation I haven't earned due to the limit?

Comment: You're not notified of any new upvotes after hitting the cap, unfortunately. You can check [your reputation tab, and sort by "time"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2788131/d4v1d?tab=reputation&sort=time), and it will show new upvotes in yellow.

Comment: Okay, so the counter just *does* and *will* always show the reputation I have **actually** earned. Thanks again!

Comment: What'll happen to the reputation after 290 ?? Won't they added later ? @Scimonster

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi No, they just get lost.